# Protocolo RTSP com primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces, streaming, rtsp

Estou tentando implementar com primefaces para aceitar o protocolo RTSP:

```
<p:media value="rtsp://myUrl" width="190" height="250">
                            <f:param name="autoPlay" value="false" />
                        </p:media>
```

Há alguma maneira de exibir o protocolo RTSP com primefaces ?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml

Comment: Já tentou usar a tag video do html5?

Comment: Ainda não, HTML5 suporta RTSP ?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5

Comment: Vou verificar, obrigado !

Comment: Ocorre o seguinte erro Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME mas a url esta correta

Comment: Eu achei isso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553136/html5-video-rtsp-not-working

Comment: E você conseguiu uma alternativa para funcionar?

Comment: Algumas alteranativas, mas são desktops, estou pensando em usar ActiveX, estou pequisando, mas parece que vai ser descontinuado.